# How to list the columns of a table in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have been googling and searching this site but cant find an answer to this simple question.

How can I list or select all the columns of a table in Teradata?

Comment: `select ColumnName from dbc.columns where DatabaseName = <'DB_NAME'> and
TableName = <'table_name'>;`

Answer (score 14):

different possibillities

```
Help table <TableName> -- All columns of a table 
Help columns  <ViewName>.* -- All columns of a View
Show table <TableName> -- DDL of table
Show view <ViewName> -- DDL of View
show select * from  <ViewName>-- DDL of base table in a view
```

or select from system table.

```
SELECT ColumnName 
FROM dbc.columnsV
WHERE DatabaseName = 'DB_NAME' and
TableName = 'table_name';
```

Searching for `teradata column name list` gives some more answers.